# Eclipse TFS plugin - Access Denied issue when pushing project to git from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs, azure-devops, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm using Eclipse as my java IDE and would like to share my project with my git repository which is under my visual studio 2013 online account.

I'm using [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913026.aspx) to integrate my Eclipse projects with TFS.
I have a test project in my workspace which I've shared (using [step 3 of the guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568708.aspx)).

Now I'm trying to check-in my project (push to git repo) but getting the following message:

[image]

My permissions for the source control are set as follows:

[image]

And the team project is assigned with the following groups:

[image]

what am I missing?

Comment: Can you describe your workflow? You have one screenshot that shows a permission problem with the TFVC (not Git) project `$/Test` and another that shows permissions for the Git (not TFVC) project "JWilhelm".  What do these two things have to do with one another?

Comment: Sure, JWilhelm is the team project and I would like to manage my code using TFVC (which uses git). I installed git on my local machine, created a local Eclipse Java project, added and committed the project to my local git and now would like to push it to TFVC. Make sense?

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Tried lot many. But, couldn't resolve. I decided to uninstall TFS and then, configured git. Now, that's the only way I could check in my code!.